# OOP and heap/stack

Tags: java, c++, oop

I have a class which looks like this

```
class A
{
    int b;

    void B()
    {
        int c;
    } 
}


int main()
{
    A asdf;

    A fdsa = new A();
}
```

What's the difference between asdf and fdsa instances of class A? In both cases which goes to the stack and which goes to the heap?

b variable inside of class A is a global variable and should get a space in heap no matter how the class was declared, correct?

Also do copies of function B is assigned to the heap and executed from there?

Comment: Are you sure your code compile in C++? I believe it won't.

Comment: What is K++? Does not seems to be a programming language (or please give an URL). Did you mean C++ ? Then I claim that the code you posted does not compile (because pointers are not the same as objects), because `A fdsa = new A();` is invalid (should be `A* fdsa= new A();`). Please take several hours to **read a good book on C++ programming**

Comment: What do you mean by K++ not being a programming language? It's a solid language. It has tons of compilers for it and millions of users worldwide.

Comment: Please give references. I am not able to find any reference about  K++ programming language, but of course I do know about [C++ programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) - and I actually do contribute to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), one of the leading free compiler for C++ ....

Comment: Is this a joke? Just type in K++ into google and it will turn up millions of references, examples and tutorials for it.

Comment: Please **give some URL on `K++`**; I did gave one on C++ and was not able to google K++ programming language.

Comment: Might be google giving up different results because of location filtering.

Comment: Kould not find anything about K++, K#, Kava... (edit: my bad, Kava indeed exists)

Comment: There is also [kaya](http://kayalang.org/), a web programming language...

Comment: @InstallGentoo: still waiting for a reference to *K++ programming language* ..... Any documents or software about it?

Comment: I can not put up links because of my low reputation. Upvote my questions so I can post links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asdf` goes to stack while `fdsa` goes to heap.

Comment: Also, I think fdsa should be a pointer cause it needs to point to the instance of class A.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `fsda` is a declared as `A*` (i.e. a pointer):

- `asdf.b` is on the stack.
- `fsda->b` is on the heap.
- Whenever you call `A::B()`, `c` goes on the stack.

Comment: And it should be `fdsa->b` not `fdsa.b` !

Answer (score 1):

First of all fdsa should be a pointer.

```
A a_on_stack; // Destroys when going out of scope
A* a_on_heap = new A(); // Need to call "delete a_on_head;" to remove from memory
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There are no *stack* or *heap* places in memory in C++ standard. They're implementation specifics.

```
A asdf;
```

It's a automatic object which allocates and destroys automatically.

```
A *fdsa = new A();
```

It's a dynamic and non-automatic object which the allocating and destroying should manage by you.

---

The only thing about *stack* in standard is,  *“stack unwinding.”* :

> The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed
>   on the path from a try block to the point where an exception is thrown
>   is called “stack unwinding. [§15.2/3]